# Datetime field value getting reduced by 1 day while converting XML data into @table values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

From my C# application I am getting the XML data as like below

```
'<NewDataSet>  
     <tblCFSPFSDDeclaration>
        <PKCFSPFSDDeclaration>-1</PKCFSPFSDDeclaration>
        <FKCFSPStatus>2</FKCFSPStatus>
        <FKBatch>EDCCCL05070801</FKBatch>
        <SDWCountSubmitted>112</SDWCountSubmitted>
        <SDWCountAccepted>112</SDWCountAccepted>
        <CFSPTraderRole>EDCCCL</CFSPTraderRole>
        <TurnNo>120220002000</TurnNo>
        <CFSPTraderLocation>EDCCCL001</CFSPTraderLocation>
        <FSDPeriod>2016-04-01T00:00:00+01:00</FSDPeriod>
     </tblCFSPFSDDeclaration>
  </NewDataSet>'
```

You can see that the FSDPeriod is 01/Apr/2016

But when I run the below query after inserting the data into a temporary table I am getting the FSDPeriod value as 31/Mar/2016

```
DECLARE @ID xml

 SET @ID=
  '<NewDataSet>  
     <tblCFSPFSDDeclaration>
        <PKCFSPFSDDeclaration>-1</PKCFSPFSDDeclaration>
        <FKCFSPStatus>2</FKCFSPStatus>
        <FKBatch>EDCCCL05070801</FKBatch>
        <SDWCountSubmitted>112</SDWCountSubmitted>
        <SDWCountAccepted>112</SDWCountAccepted>
        <CFSPTraderRole>EDCCCL</CFSPTraderRole>
        <TurnNo>120220002000</TurnNo>
        <CFSPTraderLocation>EDCCCL001</CFSPTraderLocation>
        <FSDPeriod>2016-04-01T00:00:00+01:00</FSDPeriod>
     </tblCFSPFSDDeclaration>
  </NewDataSet>'

 --2016-05-07T07:49:39+01:00

  DECLARE @hDoc int -- handle to the xml document

    DECLARE @tblCFSPFSDDeclaration TABLE 
    (
       PKCFSPFSDDeclaration bigint,
       FKCFSPStatus int ,
       FKBatch  varchar(20) ,
       ChiefBatchRef    varchar(20),
       SDWCountSubmitted    int ,
       SDWCountAccepted int ,
       TurnNo   varchar(15) ,
       CFSPTraderRole   varchar(12) ,
       CFSPTraderLocation   varchar(14) ,
       FSDPeriod    datetime    
    )

    EXECUTE sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc output, @ID -- Open the document

    INSERT INTO @tblCFSPFSDDeclaration 
                      ( 
                        [FKCFSPStatus]  ,
                        [FKBatch]  ,
                        [SDWCountSubmitted]  ,
                        [SDWCountAccepted] ,
                        [TurnNo] ,
                        [CFSPTraderRole],
                        [CFSPTraderLocation],
                        [FSDPeriod]
                      )
    SELECT              [FKCFSPStatus]  ,
                        [FKBatch]  ,
                        [SDWCountSubmitted]  ,
                        [SDWCountAccepted] ,
                        [TurnNo] ,
                        [CFSPTraderRole],
                        [CFSPTraderLocation],
                        [FSDPeriod] 
    FROM OPENXML(@hDoc,'/NewDataSet/tblCFSPFSDDeclaration', 2)
    WITH 
    (
       [FKCFSPStatus]   int ,
       [FKBatch]    varchar(20) ,  
       [SDWCountSubmitted]  int ,
       [SDWCountAccepted]   int ,
       [TurnNo] varchar(15) ,
       [CFSPTraderRole] varchar(12) ,
       [CFSPTraderLocation] varchar(14) ,
       [FSDPeriod]  datetime
    )



    select * from @tblCFSPFSDDeclaration
```

Can anyone help to get the data as 01/Apr/2016?

Comment: please check the timezone

Comment: How can i check time zone in the query above

Comment: can you see the table date what contains the [FSDPeriod] column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will solve your problem.

```
Declare the [FSDPeriod]  as datetimeoffset.
```

then you can cast them as you need. If you want only date and time then try this

```
select Convert(varchar(19), cast([FSDPeriod]as datetime),120) from @tblCFSPFSDDeclaration
```

for more conversion see here [conversion helps](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/)

Answer (score 0):

Due to supplied timezone information in the xml, SQL Server normalizes the value to UTC.

> 2016-04-01T00:00:00+01:00

When you would omit the timezone info, you would see the value you expect.

> 2016-04-01T00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone help to get the data as 01/Apr/2016?

Change `[FSDPeriod]  datetime` to `[FSDPeriod]  varchar(19)` and you will extract the `datetime` value without the timezone information. That value will be implicitly converted to a `datetime` when you insert to the table variable.